# The sine transform of symmetric functions

Tags: fourier-transform, even-and-odd-functions

I am trying to think about the sine transform of symmetric functions, chiefly the unit rectangle and the unit triangle function. I am poor with LaTeX so I'll do this as best I can

Say I have the Triangle function. Then, its sine transform is defined as

$$\int_{-1}^0(t+1)\sin(2\pi s t) d t + \int_0^1 (1-t)\sin(2\pi s t) d t$$

Now, since the triangle function is an even function, and the sine function is an odd function, the odd function times an even function gives me an odd function. Knowing that the interval of the FT integral will be symmetric, these facts lead me to conclude the Sine transform of the Triangle function is zero.

This also leads me to believe that the cosine transform of the triangle function is equal to the Fourier transform of the triangle function, strictly because the sine transform is zero.

Is my train of thought correct?

Comment: I've taken the liberty to type up the expressions in the linked image. If I introduced any error, please point it out or feel free to edit it. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: As long as the integral on $t\ge0$ converges, you're right; otherwise, the integrals on $\Bbb R$ for which you claim a value are undefined.

Comment: Your function can be defined as $f(t)=\left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 1-t & 0<t\leq 1 \\
 t-1 & 1<t\leq 2 \\
 f((t \bmod 2)) & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}\right.\right)$ which is not an even function of $x$, whereas $g(t)=f(t)-\frac{1}{2}$ is an even function of $x$.

Comment: I should be be more clear: f(t)=Triangle(t). However, if I have a shifted triangle in the t-domain (Triangle(t-a) for example), the FT is no longer zero, correct?